# ExecutorService with backpressure

Tags: java, concurrency, semaphore, executorservice, java.util.concurrent

I've got following requirements to an `ExecutorService`:

- **limited number of concurrently processing tasks** (threads), preferably configurable
- when all threads are occupied, subsequently submitted tasks get **queued**.
- the queue should apply **backpressure**: if too many tasks are submitted and the queue is full, the submission should **block**.
- the blocking submission can have a **timeout**: if a task is not submitted within a given time, an exception should be thrown.

Reason: the producers of the tasks may overwhelm the executor service or queue, resulting in an increased memory demand if too many tasks are in the queue. The backpressure will block the producers in such a situation, until the processing can catch up. The producers (some reading from Kafka, other reading from JDBC) may have open transactions which can timeout, so the submission of new tasks, if blocking, should be able to time out as well.

As the executor service implementations, such as the `ThreadPoolExecutor`, use a `BlockingQueue` to enqueue tasks, I would have expected that the queue would actually have such a feature to only queue up to a defined number of tasks and then blocking until tasks are pulled from the queue by the worker threads. Instead it turned out that when the queue is full, additional tasks are rejected with a `RejectedExecutionException` on submission. This is certainly not what I want.

I came up with a wrapper for the `ExecutorService`, which uses a `Semaphore` to control how many tasks are concurrently accepted, which also allows me to block (with a timeout) when all permits of the Semaphore are acquired:

```
public class Pipeline {

    private final ExecutorService executorService;
    private final Semaphore semaphore;

    private final int queueTimeout;
    private final TimeUnit queueTimeoutUnit;

    public Pipeline(int maxConcurrent, int queueTimeout, TimeUnit queueTimeoutUnit) {
        semaphore = new Semaphore(maxConcurrent);
        executorService = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();

        this.queueTimeout = queueTimeout;
        this.queueTimeoutUnit = queueTimeoutUnit;
    }

    public <T> Future<T> submit(Callable<T> task) {
        try {
            boolean acquired = semaphore.tryAcquire(queueTimeout, queueTimeoutUnit);
            if (!acquired) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Timeout accepting task");
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        return executorService.submit(() -> {
            try {
                return task.call();
            } finally {
                semaphore.release();
            }
        });
    }

    public void shutdown() {
        executorService.shutdown();
    }
}
```

This actually works, but seems like a common enough use case that may already be covered in the Java API. Am I missing some built-in functionality for this?

Comment: "*seems like a common enough use case that may already be covered in the Java API*" Disagree with that. Your requirements are quite specific. In most cases, if you're pushing a task to an executor then you don't want to have to block until it can start.

Comment: Re, "I would have expected that the queue would actually have such a feature..." The constructors for [`ThreadPoolExecutor`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html) let you provide your own queue.

Comment: @SolomonSlow the implementation of the `ThreadPoolExecutor` uses the `offer` method (the variant without the timeout) of the `BlockingQueue`, not the (potentially blocking) `add` method, and rejects tasks if they can't be added immediately.

Answer (score 1):

What if you create a `ThreadPoolExecutor`, and you provide a fixed-length `ArrayBlockingQueue` and your own custom `RejectedExecutionHandler`?

NOTE! I have *not* tried this myself. It's just an idea.

```java
import java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionHandler;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

class MyHandler implements RejectedExecutionHandler {
    final BlockingQueue<Runnable> task_queue;
    final long timeout;
    final TimeUnit unit;

    public MyHandler(
        BlockingQueue<Runnable> task_queue,
        long timeout,
        TimeUnit unit
    ) {
        this.task_queue = task_queue;
        this.timeout = timeout;
        this.unit = unit;
    }

    @override
    public void rejectedExecution(
        Runnable task,
        ThreadPoolExecutor pool
    ) {
        boolean timed_out = false;
        try {
            timed_out = ! task_queue.offer(task, timeout, unit);
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            ...use your shameful imagination here...
        }
        if (timed_out) {
            throw new RejectedExecutionException("queue is full");
        }
    }
}
```

Then, create the executor:

```java
BlockingQueue<Runnable> task_queue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(...);
ExecutorService pool = new ThreadPoolExecutor(
    corePoolSize,  maximumPoolSize,
    keepAliveTime, keepAliveTimeUnit,
    task_queue,
    new MyHandler(task_queue, submitTimeout, submitTimeoutUnit)
);
```

It's a bit hack-y because it messes with the queue behind the executor's back, but my expectation is, if the queue is full when your code calls `pool.submit(task)`, then the `rejectedExecution()` method of the handler will be called. It will wait for the specified amount of time to add the task to the queue.

If it succeeds, then the task is added to the queue, and everybody's happy. If it fails, then the `RejectedExecutionException` will be propagated back for the caller of `pool.submit(task)` to catch and handle however you see fit.

Comment: This implementation goes against the intended usage of the `RejectedExecutionHandler`. As stated by the docs: Method `getQueue()` allows access to the work queue for purposes of monitoring and debugging. Use of this method for any other purpose is strongly discouraged. Two supplied methods, `remove(Runnable)` and `purge` are available to assist in storage reclamation when large numbers of queued tasks become canceled.

Answer (score 0):

This is something that's missing from the standard library and why the LMAX Disruptor library exists:

https://lmax-exchange.github.io/disruptor/

My experience is it makes concurrent message queue a breeze - no threading code required at all. The caveat is that significant cpu resource is required for the lowest-latency wait strategies.